# What package should i use to replace "android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule" in the newest AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-package-managers

I've been debugging a program in AndroidStudio. The program needs the class "ActivityTestRule" but it shows:

> “Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityTestRule' ”

[-the code where ActivityTestRule is used-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKO03.png)

I'm using the newest version of AndroidStudio with the newest version of gradle. It suggests that there's no android support-v7. So I use "androidx.test" to replace most packages under "android.support.test", but I cannot find the package to replace "android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule".

What should i do? (Better just change the "import" part of code)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've solved this myself :

```
Project structure -> Add the dependency "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2" to app denpendencies ->Apply->Done.
```

In code :

```
#import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
```